# Convert decimal to percentage

Tags: vba, excel

I'm receiving data like below from an external source

[image]

What I need is to convert all highlighted data to percentage and I can't lost the part after the comma. 
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
For Each actCell In shRecipiente.ListObjects("tblRecipiente").ListColumns("All-In Rate").DataBodyRange
    If Not (Right(actCell.NumberFormat, 1) = "%") Then
        actCell.Value = Format(actCell, "#.####%")
    End If
Next actCell
```

But I'm getting for example 396,83% instead of 3,9683%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
actCell.value = Format(actCell, "#.####%")
```

to

```
actCell.value = Format(actCell / 100, "#.####%")
```

However, if it is no real % value you neet to change it to

```
actCell.value = Format(actCell, "#.####""%""")
```

or if you cant change the values try

```
actCell.Offset.NumberFormat = "#.####""%"""
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still not working, now I'm getting 39683% instead of 3,9683%

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the source

Comment: hah... that may be the problem... so you need something different... try my last option

Answer (score 0):

Divide the number by 100 and format as a percentage.

`=A1/100`

Edit - to check which is formatted as a percentage and which isn't use:
`=IF(CELL("format",A1)="P0",A1,A1/100)` - P0 indicates a percentage format.
The formula will display all the numbers without percentages, so 150% will display as 1.5, as will 150.
Then it's just a case of formatting the entire column back to percentages.